# Spark Ignite 2.8.1 throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/index/BaseIndex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

I'm following a simple example for SPARK IGNITE Dataframe and I've been getting the following error.

The usecase is simple, I want to read files convert to DF and write it to ignite, later on read the same data from Ignite

build.sbt

```
name := "spark-word-count"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark" % "2.8.1"
)
```

WordCount.scala

```
val linesRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile(filesPath)
val filesProcessed = sparkSession.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(filesPath).count()

val filteredLinesRDD = if (cacheType.isDefined) {
  getFilteredRDD(linesRDD).persist(cacheType.get)
} else {
  getFilteredRDD(linesRDD)
}
val processedLines = filteredLinesRDD.count()

sparkSession.createDataFrame(getPhraseSizesRDD(filteredLinesRDD))
  .toDF("Phrase", "Size")
  .write.format(FORMAT_IGNITE)
  .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, igniteConfigFile)
  .option(OPTION_TABLE, "PhraseSize")
  .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, "Phrase")
  .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS, "backups=1")
  .option(OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE, "true")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

ERROR Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/index/BaseIndex
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.inClassPath(IgniteUtils.java:1727)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.inClassPath(IgniteComponentType.java:160)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeDefaultSpi(IgnitionEx.java:2480)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:2328)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1697)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:637)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:412)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.ignite(IgniteContext.scala:150)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.<init>(IgniteContext.scala:63)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext$.apply(IgniteContext.scala:192)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.igniteContext(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:248)
at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.createRelation(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
```

Removing the ignite indexing solved the above error but end up with different error:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ("org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark" % "2.8.1")
  .exclude("org.apache.ignite", "ignite-indexing")
  .exclude("com.h2database", "h2"),
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197"
)
```

ERROR:

```
20/06/01 23:29:41 ERROR WordCountMain: Error executing WordCountJobMain: WordCountJob is failure 
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to execute query because indexing is disabled (consider adding module ignite-indexing to classpath or moving it from 'optional' to 'libs' folder).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.checkxEnabled(GridQueryProcessor.java:2217)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2388)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2323)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2296)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryHelper$.createTable(QueryHelper.scala:64)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.createRelation(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at main.scala.WordCountJob$.doRun(WordCountJob.scala:43)
```

Comment: why would you remove the indexing? Shouldn't you just add the H2 dependency if this is was missing? Although it should be included transitively. Do you run it locally or do you submit it on a Spark cluster as a JAR file? IF so, you need to create an Uber JAR which includes all classes from dependencies needed for running you app.

Comment: If you look at the first example that I tried I was getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/index/BaseIndex
When I only added H2 dependency I got similar error

Comment: well, I understand the error. one more time, **how** do you run your code? Do you submit your application to a running Spark cluster?

Comment: Could you please update your question with details about how you've added h2 dependency? And about how you build & deploy, the root of the evil 99% resides here.